# cgi scripts with no server

Tags: python

My goal is to use to make it easy for non-programmers to execute a Python script with fairly complex options, on a single local machine that I have access to.  I'd like to use the browser (specifically Safari on OS X) as a poor man's GUI.  A short script would process the form data and then send it on to the main program(s).

I have some basic examples of python scripts run using the built-in Apache server, by clicking submit on a form whose html is th:

[image]

e.g. [here](http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2010/11/simple-server-running-python-script-on_17.html).  What I want to do now is do it *without* the server, just getting the form to invoke the script in the same directory.  Do I have to learn javascript or ...?  I'd be grateful for any leads you have.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense -- what a browser does when it submits a form by definition is to make a request to a web server.

If all that's going on is that you don't want to be running Apache, you could hook something simple up using the [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html) class that's provided as part of the Python Standard library.

If you don't want a server process at all, and you're using a suitably modern browser, you may want to look at using HTML5 local storage, but that's not a Python solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there always has to be some kind of "server" involved to communicate over HTTP. You could have a python script listening on port 80 on your machine, that in turn runs the scripts specified with the form's action attribute.

You won't get away without some sort of server, I'm afraid.

PS: There are already a couple of good minimalistic python HTTP servers that would do the trick. Just google for it.

Regards, aefxx

Answer (score 2):

[Pyjamas Desktop](http://pyjs.org/) will allow you to deploy a browser-based desktop application.